# How to cancel debounced inside function with Lodash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, lodash, debouncing

I'm implementing a feature, allow user typing for searching automatically.
It's working properly for now.

To improve this function, I would like to support user press Enter then searching Ajax request must be called immediately.

I had read Lodash documentation. It says I can call `debounced.flush`.
OK for now. Assign the method to variable.

```
  const debounced = _.debounce((event) => {
    // Call ajax request and sth more here)
  }, 700);

  $('input').unbind('keyup keypress').on('keyup keypress', debounced);
```

For checking "Enter" button is pressed, I need to check `event.keyCode || event.which` and call the `flush` method inside the debounce function definition.

```
  const debounced = _.debounce((event) => {
    if (13 === (event.keyCode || event.which)) return debounced.flush();

    // Call ajax request and sth more here)
  }, 700);
```

But it seems the request still delay and did not be called.

Answer (score 1):

Since `debounced` would invoke the callback function only 700ms after the last time it was called, the `enter` check would also be applied only 700ms after you pressed enter.

Create an event handler that calls `debounced`, and flushes it if enter is pressed.

```js
const debounced = _.debounce(value => {
  console.log(value);
}, 700);

const eventHandler = e => {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') return debounced.flush();
  
  debounced(e.target.value);
}

$('input').on('keyup keypress', eventHandler);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<input>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try your solution and reply you